# Edit Cart on Html template

Tags: html, templates, edit, cart

on the cart page, Quantity, delete button, update cart, Subtotal, Shipping, Total, is not working at all, how i can make them work? This is all i have for cart page:
Also here is the link where you can see it http://194.110.247.137/cart.html.
Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Bootstrap4 Shop Template, Created by Imran Hossain from https://imransdesign.com/">

    <!-- title -->
    <title>Cart</title>

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
    <!-- google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <!-- magnific popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <!-- animate css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
    <!-- mean menu css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/meanmenu.min.css">
    <!-- main style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <!-- responsive -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <!--PreLoader-->
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader-inner">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--PreLoader Ends-->
    
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="top-header-area" id="sticker">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <div class="main-menu-wrap">
                        <!-- logo -->
                        <div class="site-logo">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- logo -->

                        <!-- menu start -->
                        <nav class="main-menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="current-list-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Static Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="index_2.html">Slider Home</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="404.html">404 page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="checkout.html">Check Out</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="single-news.html">Single News</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="checkout.html">Check Out</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="single-product.html">Single Product</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="header-icons">
                                        <a class="shopping-cart" href="cart.html"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a class="mobile-hide search-bar-icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <a class="mobile-show search-bar-icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                        <div class="mobile-menu"></div>
                        <!-- menu end -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end header -->

    <!-- search area -->
    <div class="search-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <span class="close-btn"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></span>
                    <div class="search-bar">
                        <div class="search-bar-tablecell">
                            <h3>Search For:</h3>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Keywords">
                            <button type="submit">Search <i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end search arewa -->
    
    <!-- breadcrumb-section -->
    <div class="breadcrumb-section breadcrumb-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 text-center">
                    <div class="breadcrumb-text">
                        <p>Fresh and Organic</p>
                        <h1>Cart</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end breadcrumb section -->

    <!-- cart -->
    <div class="cart-section mt-150 mb-150">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                    <div class="cart-table-wrap">
                        <table class="cart-table">
                            <thead class="cart-table-head">
                                <tr class="table-head-row">
                                    <th class="product-remove"></th>
                                    <th class="product-image">Product Image</th>
                                    <th class="product-name">Name</th>
                                    <th class="product-price">Price</th>
                                    <th class="product-quantity">Quantity</th>
                                    <th class="product-total">Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="table-body-row">
                                    <td class="product-remove"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="product-image"><img src="assets/img/products/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""></td>
                                    <td class="product-name">Strawberry</td>
                                    <td class="product-price">$85</td>
                                    <td class="product-quantity"><input type="number" placeholder="0"></td>
                                    <td class="product-total">1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="table-body-row">
                                    <td class="product-remove"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="product-image"><img src="assets/img/products/product-img-2.jpg" alt=""></td>
                                    <td class="product-name">Berry</td>
                                    <td class="product-price">$70</td>
                                    <td class="product-quantity"><input type="number" placeholder="0"></td>
                                    <td class="product-total">1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="table-body-row">
                                    <td class="product-remove"><a href="#"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="product-image"><img src="assets/img/products/product-img-3.jpg" alt=""></td>
                                    <td class="product-name">Lemon</td>
                                    <td class="product-price">$35</td>
                                    <td class="product-quantity"><input type="number" placeholder="0"></td>
                                    <td class="product-total">1</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="total-section">
                        <table class="total-table">
                            <thead class="total-table-head">
                                <tr class="table-total-row">
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="total-data">
                                    <td><strong>Subtotal: </strong></td>
                                    <td>$500</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="total-data">
                                    <td><strong>Shipping: </strong></td>
                                    <td>$45</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="total-data">
                                    <td><strong>Total: </strong></td>
                                    <td>$545</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="cart-buttons">
                            <a href="cart.html" class="boxed-btn">Update Cart</a>
                            <a href="checkout.html" class="boxed-btn black">Check Out</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="coupon-section">
                        <h3>Apply Coupon</h3>
                        <div class="coupon-form-wrap">
                            <form action="index.html">
                                <p><input type="text" placeholder="Coupon"></p>
                                <p><input type="submit" value="Apply"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end cart -->

    <!-- logo carousel -->
    <div class="logo-carousel-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="logo-carousel-inner">
                        <div class="single-logo-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/company-logos/1.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-logo-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/company-logos/2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-logo-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/company-logos/3.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-logo-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/company-logos/4.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-logo-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/company-logos/5.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end logo carousel -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-box about-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">About us</h2>
                        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-box get-in-touch">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Get in Touch</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>34/8, East Hukupara, Gifirtok, Sadan.</li>
                            <li>support@fruitkha.com</li>
                            <li>+00 111 222 3333</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-box pages">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Pages</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Shop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-box subscribe">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Subscribe</h2>
                        <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates.</p>
                        <form action="index.html">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
    
    <!-- copyright -->
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <p>Copyrights &copy; 2019 - <a href="https://imransdesign.com/">Imran Hossain</a>,  All Rights Reserved.<br>
                        Distributed By - <a href="https://themewagon.com/">Themewagon</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-right col-md-12">
                    <div class="social-icons">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end copyright -->
    
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- count down -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <!-- isotope -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.isotope-3.0.6.min.js"></script>
    <!-- waypoints -->
    <script src="assets/js/waypoints.js"></script>
    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- magnific popup -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- mean menu -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- sticker js -->
    <script src="assets/js/sticker.js"></script>
    <!-- main js -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont know what to try because i'm not that good on editing those type of templates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the template just has some hardcoded items in html but no functionality. The cart page should have a js file that handles all those functionalities that you mentioned.